What kind of cosmic event could justify the entire Solar System being uninhabitable in the near future (1000 years or less)?
Edit: In my story, characters possess very convenient and very powerful terraforming technology (so powerful that some characters are able to briefly survive on an asteroid). An important part of the story revolves around their ship being the last of humanity, so I need to explain not only why they couldn't stay on Earth, but also they didn't simply migrate to Mars, etc. I figured a reason centered around the Sun makes the most sense, but if there is a better idea to achieve this goal, I am open to it!
Original post:
I'm looking for any In my story, explorers venture out to interstellar space armed with easy-terraforming technology. An important part of the story hinges on Earth later being destroyed/rendered uninhabitable. Since the terraforming tech would mean that Mars or other rocky planets could be
I'm looking for any possible (not necessarily plausible) reason for the Sun to explode or otherwise destroy Earth in the next 1000 years or less.
The characters in my story possess technology that allows them for rapid, easy terraforming. Despite this, I need a reason for them to be forced to leave the Solar System. That's why I'd prefer for Earth (and our rocky neighbors) to be destroyed completely and relatively instantaneously. I'd prefer a reason that is naturally occurring and not directly caused by human activity, but I'm not completely closed off to the latter. There are no (known) aliens in the world of my story.
So far all I've really come up with is the improbable idea of some kind of rogue body drifting into the Solar System and colliding with the Sun, but I know the gravitation effects of this would preclude the kind of impact effects that I'm looking for. While those effects would still be fatal for Earth, again I'd prefer something more sudden that can be counted down to.

Does it need to explode - or would having a significant increase in Solar flares or a Superflare has been theorised to make earth uninhabitable.

Lots of people left England and Spain and Portugal and France and Italy and Germany and the Low Countries the Nordic countries etc. and went to the Americas and Africa and Australia etc. where they had to rebuild civilization from scratch. Call in Euroforming if you want. There was no need for England and Spain and Portugal and France and so on to be in imminent danger of destruction. People are naturally driven to explore and colonize; it is in our essence.

I agree that danger is not necessary to justify human exploration! But I have narrative reasons why I don't want returning to the Solar System to be an option.

"Don't want returning to the Solar System to be an option": Because the ship broke? Because they burned their ships? Because the ships got dismantled for parts when setting up the colony? Because of strong ideological reasons? Because from the very beginning the ships had resources for one way trip only? Etc. (My point is that if you make Earth uninhabitale you set an unnecessary constraint, which you may regret later, when e.g. you would like a plot twist.)

You make some very good points, I appreciate it! I guess I should have been more specific: a large part of my story is about the philosophical implications of being (or at least believing you are) the last surviving representatives of the human race, drifting somewhere in interstellar space. So whether or not the Earth is habitable, the explorers need to at least believe all of humanity was wiped out, and was unable to save themselves (even though this level of terraforming technology should've let them migrate to Mars, etc.) This is the real issue I'm wrestling with.

Superior Intelligence? I'm thinking something similar to Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy in which a notice is placed on a distant planet that Earth is to be destroyed for a construction project (I think; it's been a long time since I read it). For example, you have a great universal mystery or a First Contact. Either way, the message is to get the f out, or else. Planets start exploding and cosmic rays fill the solar system to make it uninhabitable. This is fiction, right?

Are you looking for "Makes the system uninhabitable for at least 1000 years" or "will wipe out the solar system within the next thousand years, but is currently undetectable." Are you needing them to be inhabitable again after 1000 years?

Whatever else, could you either drop or preferably explain the use of '… so powerful that some characters are able to briefly survive on an asteroid…'?

@AlexP the problem with "People are naturally driven to explore and colonize" is that they go and colonize places when they are motivated, and where they can survive.  It's why the Vikings didn't stay in Vinlandia, and why we haven't colonized Antarctica.

@AlexP exploration wasn't "in our essence" for 99.9% of humanity's existence (humans didn't leave Africa because they wondered what's on the other side of the river, mountain or plain; they did it because they were hungry and needed more food), and it hasn't been in 99.9% of humanity's essence for 100% of humanity's existence.

@AlexP I wouldn't call the colonization of the Americas or Australia "rebuilding civilization from scratch". Rather, "scraping them clean of their striving civilizations and building a European one on the smoking rubble thereof".

No need to invoke a stellar catastrophe. Just allow humanity to colonize our Solar system, then split the planets into Big Endians and Little Endians, provide nuclear arguments to both sides and enjoy the show. In the end, only the dissenters deported to Alpha Centauri remain online.

Not our Sun, but if some other (close enough) star were to go supernova that might do it. Right now I do not believe there are any close enough candidates to be a real danger but that's why it's fiction.

Near-Earth supernova on the Fount of All Knowledge: "Because Type Ia supernovae arise from dim, common white dwarf stars, it is likely that a supernova that could affect the Earth will occur unpredictably and take place in a star system that is not well studied; the closest known candidate is IK Pegasi" (at 46 parsecs or 150 light-years).

iirc, 150 light years is too far to have a significant effect.

@Nosajimiki: Yes, if the supernova is a bland run-of-the mill type II supernova then anything farther away than maybe 8 parsecs (26 light-years) is too far; e.g. Betelgeuse, which when it blows it will make a nice light show and nothing more. But if IK Pegasi blows it will be a superpotent a type Ia supernova, and those might be effective up to 300 parsecs (1,000 light-years).

But then all other nearby stars will be affected the same, so there will be no reason for humanity to leave the solar system in search of an unaffected planet.

@AlexP I've heard these claims before, but never seen any science to back them up.  A 1a Supernova's primary emissions are in the visible light spectrum and they have an absolute magnitude of -19.5. If Betelgeuse goes supernova, it will only have an apparent magnitude of -12.028.  This means that the total apparent luminosity of the event will be comparable to that of a full moon.  So, it will be clearly visible with the naked eye, but its effects on our environment will be negligible.

As for radiation, when you account for atmospheric attenuation, it would be 7-8 orders of magnitude too weak to cause even minor radiation sickness.

How would the ship itself survive if the planets do not?

@Trioxidane, it's a lot easier to armor a ship than it is to armor a planet.

Rogue planets
As a quick aside, consider if destruction is required. There will be interest in interstellar space at one point. Leaving the solar system and the little to no communication can already be as effective as the home star system being destroyed.
Imagine a Jupiter like planet going through the solar system. It goes horizontal with a vertical angle compared to the orbits of the planets. It shifts many out of orbit, leaving Earth to drift off with cataclysmic results from the moon leaving/crashing into the planet (possibly after a hundred years). Mars or moons like Europa might take longer and could be terraformed. However, would you terraform a planet that would need constant tending until it is too far gone to continue terraforming? Even if you could stay a year or a hundred, it can be best to start your interstellar journey to a more stable star system.
If the potential to knock half the planets out of orbit still isn't satisfying enough you can make it worse. Maybe the rogue planet rams neptune showering the rest of the system with debris. Or throws another planet towards others. The potential terraforming planets can get destroyed, or a Solar System wide Kessler syndrome makes it too dangerous to stay there. You can have the ship survive by being in the 'shadow' side of a planet when the event occurs.

You're right; I misread it. Comment rescinded (and answer upvoted).

A tilting pulsar- its jets pointing into the flightpath of the solar system, the raygun cooking the solar system for a thousand years. We wouldn't even see it coming. Just one day, gama-ray microwave, all the things. The oceans aglow from neutrino flow. Merry X-mass everybody.

No natural phenomenon exists that could achieve this timescale.
There is no cosmic event that can render the whole solar system uninhabitable given your level of terraforming in less than 1000 years.

The most powerful nearby Nova, Supernova, or GRB that could possibly happen will be 7-8 orders of magnitude too weak to harm life on Earth.
Rogue black holes and stars move too slowly. One would already have to be within 1 lightyear of us to reach us within 1000 years, at which point we would we be more than capable of detecting it already.
A rogue planet could do a lot of harm to a single planet, but they don't have enough gravity to significantly disrupt the whole solar system.
We understand solar life cycles too well for there to be any risk of our star suddenly becoming unstable in any less than about 5 billion years.

This means you need an unnatural cause
Instead of making the solar system uninhabitable from a natural disaster standpoint, it means that you need to create something that is either man or alien made. Possible examples include:

An alien invasion: Aliens come to kill us all and take our planet; so, we have to run as far and as fast as we can.
A dystopian regime: The solar system is technically inhabitable, but not a place that your protagonist group can stay if they want to live.  Maybe they are fleeing a genocide, or a political cleansing, or religious persecution, etc.
An AI or bioengineered slave uprising: Artificial slave labor rebelled and started killing all humans.  Also a genocide problem, but in this case there are no more humans left in the Sol system.
Gray Goo or super bio weapon:  Any sort of self replicating doomsday weapon.  This one is good if you want to make sure it stays in the solar system without spreading since it's possible to see the whole system infected because it hitches rides between colonies.
Industrial Waste: Perhaps there is a byproduct of human technology that slowly makes a planet uninhabitable in a way that no terraforming can fix.  Like excessive use of nuclear power making all planets too radioactive, or something like that.

The only key point is that it is a threat that your humans lack the ability to overcome so their only chance of survival is to run from it.

Rogue planet, but with a different effect
My suggestion is nearly the same as @Trioxidane's answer, but with a twist :
Instead of the rogue planet sending the rocky planets away, it disturbs their orbit so that they fall into the Sun.
Some other planets, especially the gas giants, can be send off or just be slightly disturbed, provided there is no rocky planets / rocky moons left, the Solar system is unusable even with their terraforming technology.

The rouge planet doesn't have to send rocky planets into the sun to make them uninhabitable, it would be sufficient to have the rogue planet disturb the orbits to make them uninhabitable.  There's a thin "goldilocks zone" for life and if planets are in unstable orbits that take them in and out of this zone then widely varying temperatures will sterilize planets.

@MacGuffin but if the protagonists have terraforming technology that can make an asteroid habitable, a rocky planet thrown out of the goldilocks zone surely isn't out of its capability?
I like the idea of a rogue gas giant yeeting the inner planets into the sun; moons could be destabilized enough to crash into their gas giant parents who may or may not then wander significantly off course, and Pluto and its moons for whatever they're worth could all be destabilized and smash into one another leaving debris unsuitable for habitation.

Alternatively, Pluto or Charon might be the only rocky survivors, and perhaps are where the terraformers were already set up... and their already-unstable orbits around Sol resulted in them getting thrown loose, turning their inhabitants into interstellar travelers...

@DoktorJ Yes, or they can be thrown out of the solar system. They are already really far away, even with super terraforming tech the protagonists probably still need the power of a star to make the planet livable in the long term.

First, a black hole doesn't need to be "rogue." They're often solitary. We only notice them when they aren't. We have yet to identify any black holes that aren't either supermassive or part of a binary system.
A black hole that's headed for the Sun along the polar axis, moving at a tenth the speed of light, wouldn't be noticeable based on gravity until it was inside the Oort cloud. Call it a light year. That would give us ten years to do something about it.
It might be noticeable if it passed in front of something that we were watching, but we don't have a lot of telescopes pointed that direction. It took us until 2003 to spot Eris because we weren't pointing our telescopes that way.
It would completely shred the Sun. It wouldn't be a surprise, but it would eliminate any remnants of mankind that weren't deep-space ready. It might be boring, but it's a reasonable starting place. Your backstory doesn't need to be epic or mind-bogglingly original.

Bring the rain!
You have requested something that...

Forces a quick retreat from Earth.
Won't permit terraforming inside our solar system.

I love it! Yes, we could do something to the sun. But to be honest, even our humble star is a whomping big leviathan of a critter. Doing something to an entire star is breathtaking. It would take something a lot bigger than a rogue planet hitting it to make that much of a difference — especially as the result must remain so for a long enough period of time that it makes sense to hot-foot it out of the system.
I give you the usually poorly defined but nonetheless ubiquitous ion storm.
This little bit of technobabble is used to rationalize all kinds of things in the SciFi universe. Bad navigation, space-born turbulence akin to a hurricane during the Age of Sail, communications drop-out, infertility in the Tasmanian Wombat... all kinds of things. But let's take the idea a step further.
Everything in space is in motion. All those really cool nebulae that look to be fixed in place during our fleeting lives are actually bookin' around the central core of the galaxy right along with us. And therein lies the core of the idea: we want a cloud of particles that are bad for humans! A cloud big enough to swamp the entire solar system. Considering most nebulae encompass many star systems, that's not a stretch to believe at all.
Now, why is it bad for us? That's a bit of a dealer's choice. Radioactive particles (aka "fallout") are possible, but tend to be short-lived in astronomical terms. Whatever this cloud is, it had to travel the vast reaches of space to get here. What if we're talking about a cloud that's been accelerated to a good percentage of light speed? Maybe 10%-15% (not completely out of reach, yes?). Unbeknownst to humanity a nebula that was at exactly the wrong place at the wrong time when a Series of Unfortunate Events took place (a supernova, a burst from a pulsar, slingshot around a black hole at exactly the right distance...) to get it up to speed.
And whatever that story-based glorious event was, it set a small nebula of nasty on course for the Sol system. Without proper backlighting, we can't see it — but it's coming! And it's large enough to envelop the solar system for decades, possibly centuries! After all, gold old Sol is only cruising through space at about 720,000 km/hr, which sounds whomping fast, but in astronomical terms, it's a gentle stroll compared to the 107-162 million km/h that cloud's moving at.
However, unlike many a nebula, this cloud is unusually dense. Most nebulae are such low density that if you were actually inside one you wouldn't really know it (other than scientifically). But who knows how many planets were ripped to shreds to form this cloud? Billions and billions! So...

A cloud exists, it's the size of a small nebula but large enough to take the solar system at least a century to clear. That makes the cloud on the order of 4200 AU or 0.07 LY along the important axis. That's not unreasonable! So say we all.

The cloud is unusually dense. Maybe it's a dark matter cloud. Maybe it's just at the wrong angle to get a good look at it. Maybe it's a lot of golf-ball sized chunks of carbon, absorbing most light spectra.

The cloud is, one way or the other, an extinction-level event anywhere in the solar system. Could be radioactive. Could be screaming along at relativistic speeds. Could simply be made out of something yucky (let's blame that on dark matter, too! Always good to have stuff you can't prove exists floating around but that everyone believes exists) that keeps things from growing that even your terraforming tech can't overcome in time. This is your blank to fill in.

The cloud is coming from a direction that isn't well lit. And given how short the time has been that sapient humanity has trod the Earth, in astrological terms, it's really, really, really close, which makes it pretty hard to see, IMO. After all, we tend to focus on things a lot further away. Could be wrong, in which case it's time to invoke narrative necessity. Either way, it's a sudden event that would cause more than just bad comms if you're still here when it hits, so your adventurers have gotta vamoose right now!


So, interstellar acid rain... known colloquially as an "ion storm..." but you give it whatever name you want. It's fast. It's ugly. And it's moving in for a at least the lifetime of your youngest. Oh, yeah!
On the other hand, if you could stick around and look at the trailing edge of the sun, it would make a lovely comet-like tail that'll tell everybody, "this system won't be inhabitable for a century or two. Please take a number at the hospitality counter if you wish to submit a sealed bid for the system at that time."

This really seems like a less plausible version than 'nanomachines' in many other stories, isn’t it? The nebula can't be detected until too close to make sure only one ship is left. It can come from a region with little interest and stars, that is fine. The size is against it, as it is enormous. It can't be a dark nebula, or it lacks it's destructive properties. So it'll be emitting something that current telescopes can already detect. Even al 0,1c it would look like the it would be detected hundreds of years before it arrives. Not to mention it would destroy the ship as well.

@Trioxidane Enormous compared to what? Known nebulae are orders of magnitude larger. The point of accelerating it is the impact damage rationalizes the danger. After all, the OP stated I'm looking for any possible (not necessarily plausible).... But more to the point... do you have a question to improve my answer? Or are you just belleyaching?

Apologies if you feel attacked. I was searching for things I overlooked, and giving thoughts that might improve the answer. I can live with the sci-fi ideas like dark matter doing unusual stuff, but the nebula not being detected even with today's technology seemed too far fetched. You might make it more plausible by saying dark matter generates it on the spot, right over the solar system, or go fantasy and have the sun eject part if it's corona for a nebula. That doesn't assume real rules, making it easier to accept.

Two old neutrons stars in a very tight orbit are heading for the solar system.  They've slowed enough over the eons that they no longer have much of a jet and they're pointed away from the solar system anyway.  They could get pretty close before they're picked up.
And the clock is going to run down, they're going to merge as they pass near the solar system.  (Yes, you could probably survive the boom if you were hiding behind a planet.  That's assuming you know accurately enough when it will go boom...)

'holes!
Not black holes.  Not Q's holes or S's holes; somewhere in between, perhaps.  We're speaking of the sort of holes who load holes full up soman and VX and biological weapons genetically radiation-hardened to remain infectious in deep space conditions for decades.  Stored drones that can circle the Earth, Mars, etc. for ten years, armed with a gun that shoots nuclear bullets with enough freshly purified copernicium-293 to crack open an asteroid.
Since you want the Sun to be involved, I'll put the physically biggest holes on Mercury; there holes near the poles boast frozen water and a narrow zone of habitable conditions, while remaining close to towers that hold solar panels in perpetual hottest sunlight, and mirrors that can power massive foundries.  Mercury is a hard planet to get to (high delta vee) and the robot defense systems see you coming.  At least a hero in a spaceship gets a quick death in a hail of railgun fire, rather than ingesting an engineered endospore that triggers irregular shards of bone to form randomly in his brain, eyes, skin and joints.
Mercury's factories were highly automated, the source of great wealth for many in the Solar system, and it took a single sneak attack to turn the planet into the source of a sphere of military spacecraft that surrounds the sun.  Once there was a human tyrant and minions who claimed the system, but their lethal contagions and killer robots must have gotten the upper hand at some point.  Now the machines watch everything, attacking anything that can be observed to change, all AI-controlled.  Like Diamonds are Forever but aimed at everything in the Solar system.  Whether you land on Callisto or Pluto, your space suit will get contaminated with obscene chemicals and organisms your best scrubbers will fail to clean, contact with which assures miserable death.  The holdouts on the dark side of Eris or cowering in the L2 point of Jupiter will see no choice but to cut and run... and pray the blasted machines don't send care packages to nearby stars.

Frame challenge: This answers the "why they didn't simply migrate to Mars", while leaving the rest of our solar system unscathed.
They developed the terraforming capability AFTER they left Earth

First, they leave Earth, targeting some distant world (many possible reasons: it may be because they anticipate the coming demise of Earth, or simply because of human's obsession with exploration and/or conquest).

At this time, they do not have terraforming capabilities (or not to the extent required), and Mars is not a viable option, so they target a planet far far away which is more adequate.

Later (en route, or after having set up camp on that planet far far away), they develop additional technologies which enable them to terraform about any lump of rock.


Also note that 1000 years (about 40 generations) is probably nearly enough time for Foundation-type or Battlestar Galatica-type "we established ourselves in a place far far away and much later searched for our origin planet".

Something like this is probably impossible to happen with our current understanding of the universe, and something large enough to collide with the Sun would likely be something we would already know about. However, there is something I think you might be able to get away with ...
Strange Matter.
If the strange matter hypothesis is true, then there should be a low chance that normal matter could spontaneously change into strange matter, which might, under some interpretations of current physics, converge adjacent regular matter into strange matter. For regular matter beings like ourselves, this transformation would not be survivable.
If the sun was converted into strange matter, this would compromise the entire solar system and render it uninhabitable. I'd imagine this would lead to some major shift in the energy output of the Sun, and if that wasn't enough this strange matter star would spread its matter across the solar system, "infecting" planets and converting them to strange matter.
This is extremely unlikely to happen in any case, and might not be true in real life. But there are some benefits:

Solar system is uninhabitable to humans permanently ...
Due to natural processes ...
In a way that you could probably spin to be plausible with our current understanding of physics.

As a bonus, there could be a risk of this strange matter spreading to nearby star systems (however low), which could be an impetus for your burgeoning civilisation to move as far away from Sol as they can.
EDIT: There's a fourth benefit: this doesn't rule out human activity leading to the Sol system becoming uninhabitable, if you want to keep your worlds open. We haven't produced any strange matter so it's mostly a theoretical construct, which also means that scientists may want to produce a small amount to learn more about the universe.
If you wanted to, your protagonists could involve a group opposed to this experiment that was ultimately unable to prevent it, and a possible plot hook could be that due to efforts outside of the protagonists' control, the experiment will happen at a specific time, and the protagonists know that this will destroy the solar system. So they must build an interstellar ship to save whoever they can win over to their side. The benefit for this in your constraints is that it provides a key deadline by which the protagonists must be levaing the solar system, but this does require that not all of human civilisation is collaborating with them (which might work in your plot, but if you've already written in unity before this you'll need some other reason for strange matter to end up in the sun).

This will be rough to justify in a way that is Realistic, but that's okay. Consider how many other famous fictional works have even less justified reasons for extra solar exploration (our crops are sick, gtg).
Leaving the solar system is a Hard problem, and there are a LOT of resources here, over a wide range of conditions.
Consider that the "easiest" thing to do to affect every planet is to tweak the sun's output energy.
Too hot and the planets boil. Too cool and they freeze.
But that's not really a problem for Terraforming level tech. Too hot? Just grab a more distant rocky body. Pluto got promoted to king Dwarf Planet because we just kept finding more and more rocks out there.
Too cold is a problem for Earth, but less of a problem than drifting through interstellar space for millennia. Most of the outer bodies are already barely heated by today's sun.
So tweaking stellar output (a massive feat on its own) isn't really going to justify an Exodus.
A "Realistic but Alien" option is a swarm of self-replicating probes consuming all the rocky matter in the solar system, but uh, good luck finding a second dry tree to hide under in the rain.
By far the most rational explanation is that another star has drifted into Sol's gravity well, and the perturbations will chaotically destabilize every planetary orbit for an unknowable duration.
A rogue black hole or neutron star would be the best candidates. A neutron star would probably be seen from a long, LONG way off though, so let's stick with a small black hole approaching from above the orbital plane.
It isn't that the entire solar system is guaranteed to be rendered permanently uninhabitable, it is that you can't predict how habitable any given body will remain (Thanks, three+ body problem).
It is better to just leave and find a more stable system, even if the journey will be rough.

Blackholes and stars don't move fast enough relative to each other for us to not know about one that is less than 1000 years away from us right now.

@Nosajimiki A blackhole that is already "on its way" could be very difficult to spot directly. It would indeed need to be going "relatively slowly" to actually get captured, but even a quick flyby could cause enough destabilization to justify the Narrative.

You would not have to see it directly.  It's effects on the motion of the stars in the local star cluster would be very noticable.  The fastest another astral body might conceivably move relative to us would be about 200kps which means that it would already have to be within 1 light year of us to pass through our solar system within the next 1000 years, yet we study gravitational effects on stars so slight that we can notice the effects of black holes on stars that are thousands of lightyears away.

We're crafting a justification for something that isn't realistically justifiable. It just needs to pass the sniff test for an audience. Very Successful movies have gotten people to leave our solar system for much, much flimsier reasons

Gratefully, Real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested, and without even the [tag:science-based] tag, that leaves us open to the wonderful world of suspension of disbelief. Thank goodness.
